# Can anyone work out how to test this OCAML function?

Tags: function, ocaml, first-order-logic

I'm working through a practice paper for an exam but there are no answers.
There are a series of functions which I have to explain what they do but there is one I can't solve:
`fun x -> fun y -> (x y);;`
It has the type:
`('a -> 'b) -> 'a -> 'b`
What am I supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean by "*how to test*"? Can you describe what the function does? What are its parameters? What does it do with them?

Comment: @Bergi I don't know what it does. This is what I wrote in the file and I want to test it in the terminal. I expected to write something like ```(fun x -> fun y -> (x y)2 3);;```

Comment: Assign the function to a variable, like `let f = fun x -> fun y -> (x y);;`. Then you can call it like `f 2 3`. But you really should try to learn how to find out what the function does by reading the code, not only by trying it out (running it).

Comment: Do you know what the expression `(x y)` means in OCaml?

Comment: @JeffreyScofield I know x and y represent 'a and 'b but I don't know what they are doing in this function

Comment: @Bergi I tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: @Jeffrey: A function call

Comment: OP: look at @G4143's answer here.

Comment: @BenGardner I didn't say that `f 2 3` would work (as that's for you to figure out…), just meant to show as an example that `f` is now a usable function. The error message should help you.

Comment: @BenGardner No, `x` does not represent `'a` and `y` does not represent `'b`. Instead, the type of `x` is `('a -> 'b)` and the type of `y` is `'a`.

Comment: @BenGardner Another hint: the type of `(x y)` is `('b)`, the type of `fun y -> (x y)` is `'a -> ('b)`, and the type of the entire `fun x -> fun y -> (x y)` is `('a -> 'b) -> ('a -> ('b))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size:

```
let () =
  Printf.printf "The ans is: %d" ((fun x -> fun y -> (x y)) (fun x -> x + 10) 4133)
```